# Can't change Filesystem encoding in Apache → PHP → Python 3 → sys.argv

Tags: php, python, encoding, filesystems

Trying to pass some non-ASCII texts to a Python Script through arguments.

**demo.php**

```
echo shell_exec("python3 demo.py 学校");
```

**demo.py**

```
import sys
print(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
print(sys.argv)
```

When I try to run it in console (`php demo.php`), it gives the correct result.

```
UTF-8
['demo.py', '学校']
```

But when I try to run it from a browser, it inserts a `\xdc` before each non-ASCII byte:

```
ascii
['demo.py', '\udce5\udcad\udca6\udce6\udca0\udca1']
```

How can I force the filesystem encoding with PHP script?

#### Failed attempts

- All kinds of `set_locale` settings

  - `set_locale(LC_ALL, "C.UTF-8");`
  - `set_locale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");`
  - `set_locale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");`
  - etc.

Comment: It seems it's Python 2 on the server.

Comment: @NizamMohamed Python 3.5.2 both of the times, and both on the same machine.

Comment: "run it from a browser" what does that mean?

Comment: @NizamMohamed , Run the PHP file through HTTP. Something like open up `http://127.0.0.1/demo.php`. (Server hosted with Apache 2)

Comment: do check response `Content-Type` from the browser. It must be `text/plain` or `text/html` with `charset=utf-8` otherwise the browser can't decode the bytes. or just post response headers from browser's developer tools.

Comment: @NizamMohamed , In my case, the Unicode string is hardcoded in the PHP script, the browser is just merely sending a GET request to run it. Also there's `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` in the response header.

Comment: It seems Pyhthon and PHP use different text ecncodings. try `echo mb_internal_encoding();` and post it.

Comment: @NizamMohamed UTF-8 for both cases

Comment: PHP version? Is it >= 5.6?

Comment: try `declare(encoding='utf-8');` and from my shell `$env|grep LANG` is `LANG=en_IN.UTF-8
GDM_LANG=en_US
LANGUAGE=en_IN:en`

Answer (score 0):

In my case this made the trick

simply add the following two lines to 
`/etc/apache2/envvars`

```
export LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
export LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'
```

[Refer: Can't change  Filesystem encoding in Apache → PHP → Python 3 → sys.argv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398540/unicodeencodeerror-when-saving-imagefield-containing-non-ascii-characters-in-dja?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Consider explaining what the info is that is provided when following the external link. In case that link ever goes bad, users visiting this site will still have a way of knowing what you referenced ...